# Why is MySQL adding an apostrophe?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

Here is the where clause I'm building:

```
 $where = "requesterid='".$memberid."' AND recieverid='".$tomemberid."' OR requesterid='".$tomemberid."' AND recieverid='".$memberid."'";
```

Now `$memberid` and `$tomemberid` are both integers. And here is the error when I execute it:

> Unknown column 'requesterid='6'' in 'where clause'

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (`friendships`) WHERE `requesterid='6'` AND
recieverid='5' OR requesterid='5' AND recieverid='6'
```

Why is MySQL adding an apostrophe after the digit 6?  I printed out`$memberid` and it doesn't show any apostrophe or anything else after/before it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think it's adding an apostrophe - the error message it's printing out is wrapped in apostrophes, so the outermost pair are from the error message, and the inner pair are the ones wrapped around the 6.

Comment: Segmenting your AND/OR statements with parentheses will improve/correct the logic and clarify your intent. You mention in comments below that the variables are coming from query parameters…make sure you sanitize them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are numerical values you can omit the apostrophes

```
$where = "(requesterid=$memberid AND recieverid=$tomemberid) OR (requesterid=$tomemberid AND recieverid=$memberid)";
```

Comment: well now the error is even more clear lol...its still adding an apostrophe after the first 6...

Comment: are you sure it's an integer? :)

Comment: well its coming from a url paramater, the $memberid

Comment: it gave me this error:  Unknown column '$memberid' in 'where clause'

Comment: try to hardcode your `$memberid` - if it works double check it for being a valid integer

Comment: Could you echo out the SQL you're generating?

Comment: ok i fixed it.  basically the brackets helped and i think its stupid codeigniter's active record class...for some reason when doing a OR, it produces that error...so be wary of this when using codeigniter...thanks zoltan.

Comment: @dave it's not because of using an `OR`. If it were, it wouldn't be fit for purpose and it clearly is. The issue is that you weren't substituting one of the `$tomemberid`'s properly. When there's any chance of confusion, you should either use curlys ala `AND Something='{$Value}'`";` or concatenate `AND Something='" . $Value . "`";`. Of course, neither of these properly sanitise your input - you should be using parameterised queries, especially since CI gives them to you for free.

Comment: `$Results = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeId = ? And SometString=?", array(1,"A String"));` The parameters are substituted for `?`s in the query (in order) and the query is now immune to SQL injection as the engine handles the proper escaping

Comment: @dave If you're using CodeIgniter, try and use the ["query bindings" feature](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) whenever possible. Putting in raw values is extremely dangerous.